# Error in php code in this cart code

Tags: php, mysqli, global-variables

Error is showing up in my code :-

```
<?php
session_start();
$page = 'index.php';
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("not connected to db ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
function product()
{
     $sql = "select id,name,description,price from products where quantity > 0 order by id DESC" ;
     $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
     {
         echo 'no products to display';
     }
     else
     {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             echo '<div class="boxed">'.$row['name'].'<br>'.$row['price'].'<br>'.$row['description'].'<br>'.'</div>';
         }
     }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script>
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid green ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
product();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Errors are :

> Notice: Undefined variable: connection in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cart.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cart.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cart.php on line
>   12
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cart.php on line
>   18

Comment: Could you give me feedback on my answer? :) Also really consider using singleton approach.

Comment: Could you please upvote an answer if you find it useful and also mark it as accepted with the tick. If you don't know how look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error is correct the `$connection` is not accessible from the function. To make it accessible within a function you must use a `global` keyword like this:

```
function product()
{
    global $connection;
    ...
}
```

The other errors are appering because of the first one. This is also answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060465/get-variables-from-the-outside-inside-a-function-in-php) question.

**But this is not considered best practice as you can connect to database too many times for no good reason. I suggest you use a singleton class which makes sure you have only one connection open to the database. This is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793043/4965962) answer.**

Answer (score 0):

First answer is correct, or you could pass $connection to your function like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
$page = 'index.php';
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart");
function product($connection){
    $sql = "select id,name,description,price from products where quantity > 0 order by id DESC" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {
        echo 'no products to display';
    }
    else
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
         echo '<div class="boxed">'.$row['name'].'<br>'.$row['price'].'<br>'.$row['description'].'<br>'.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

...

product($connection);
```