# PHP : Using variable functions

Tags: php

I have a class that allows a PDO connection which sets itself up. When I want to use the connection I can use:

```
$db = $factory->create('db');
```

However, I wanted to just be able to do:

`global $db;`

Anytime I want to use the database.

Would this work?

```
$db = function(){
        $con = $factory->create('db');
        return $con;
    };

global $db;
```

This way, I can close the connection and then open it again at any point. Example:

```
global $db;
$db->close();
// Re-open
global $db;
```

Or how could I possibly do this? References would be so appreciated as I have searched a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you make `$db` global then whats the point for the factory pattern ?? just curious

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792974/global-variable-database-connection

Comment: I am new to protected, global and private :( I want to just be able to `global $db;` every time I want to use the database and just be able to close it and re-open it the way it says. Can anyone link me any references to achieve this?

Comment: While I don't know what `$db->close()` does, the connection is not going to magically reopen when you change the variable scope, which is all the global keyword is doing.

Comment: MyBB, you can do $db->close(); & then just global $db; to reopen the connection :/ @Devon

Comment: Then `$db->close()` probably isn't doing anything.  You should focus your learning on the proper usage and separation of variable scopes, not trying to adapt the code to how MyBB works.

Comment: So in this case I'll just have to do: `$db = $factory->create('db');` and then make it null and re-create it when I want to re-use it?

Comment: Is this your own class? What does `$factory->create('db')` and `$db->close()` exactly do?

Comment: @KyleE4K: instead of adding Solved text to topic, add an answer and accept it.

Comment: Can't accept my own answers for 2 days lol but okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Devon** explained in the *comments* section about Scopes and how this couldn't be achieved.

In order for this to work you'd just do:

```
$db = $factory->create('db');
// close it
$db = null;
// re-open it
$db = $factory->create('db');
```

Or this:

```
function db(){
    $db = $factory->create('db');
    global $db;
}

db();
$db->.....
```